# Seem things in some procession of the dead

Tags: meaning, poetry

What does seem mean in "Seem things in some procession of the dead" in Sunday Morning By WALLACE STEVENS poem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fuller quote showing the whole sentence.

> The pungent oranges and bright, green wings
>   Seem things in some procession of the dead,
>   Winding across wide water, without sound.

Perhaps "seem" is a shortened form of "seem like" or "seem to be".